# How to capture non-HTTP or HTTPS URLs in Burp

Tags: burp-suite, sniffing

I want to intercept URLs except for HTTP and HTTPS, is that possible with Burp Suite?
For example, I want to get a response of following URL in Burp Suite:

jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/chrome/toolkit/skin/classic/

How is it possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you want this? Burp can't do this but maybe we can suggest another solution to your problem.

Comment: There is a Burp [extension](https://github.com/summitt/Burp-Non-HTTP-Extension) for intercepting non-HTTP network protocols, although it can't handle the jar protocol. You can use the jar tool which is part of the JDK to look inside jar files.

Comment: Or if you don't have JDK, Java jar files are really zip files with a few special entries. If you rename the file (or a copy) with extension .zip Windows Explorer can browse it (since Vista IIRC). Note the part of the jar: URL before the exclamation point is the (jar)filename; the rest is the entry _in_ the (jar)file.

Comment: Can i also intercept chrome protocols? How can i do it? I mean the URLs like chrome://settings/help